# Can I use watch from Vue 3 with primitives?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

Every time I fetch data, I want to change boolean value to render `<Loading />` component.
I don't want my condition to be dependant on array length. So I decided to do it this way.
And `<Loading />` component never reacts to `state.isLoading` change.
I tried to test whether `this.isLoading` changes at all using `watch`. But `watch` never logged anything.
I've never seen anybody using watch with primitives.
The problem is that I don't know if I can use `watch` with primitives and what I can use instead, like `useEffect` in React.

**App.vue**

```
<script setup>
  import { RouterView } from 'vue-router'
  import { watch, ref, onMounted, reactive } from 'vue';
  import Navbar from './components/Navbar.vue'
  import { useShopStore } from './stores/shopStore';

  const shop = useShopStore()

  const bool = ref(shop.isLoading)

  console.log(bool)

  watch(bool.value, (newBool) => {
    console.log(newBool)
  }, { deep: true })
</script>
```

**Category.vue**

```
<template>
  <LoadingVue v-if="shop.isLoading" />
  <div v-else class="category__menu">
    <CardVue
      v-for="item in shop.category"
      :item="item"
      :key="item.id"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

**ShopStore.js**

```
actions: {
  async getProducts(path) {
    if (typeof path !== 'string' || path === undefined) return
    this.setLoading()
    try {
      const response = fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category/${path}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => this.category = res)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      alert('Something went wrong')
    }
    this.setLoading()
  },
  setLoading() {
    console.log('setLoading')
    this.isLoading = !this.isLoading
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use watch with ***any*** *reactive* data, meaning data created via the `ref(...)` or `reactive(...)` function call (the former for primitives). So, no, you can't watch a "naked" primitive, but you should be able to use it with wrapped primitives, as it appears you are doing, although you shouldn't have `bool.value` in the watch. It should be just `bool`, no?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Full Of Eels why it never logs when boolean value is changed?

Comment: Again, shouldn't `watch(bool.value, (newBool) => {` instead be `watch(bool, (newBool) => {`? It's the reactive value that you're watching, not the naked value.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels tried, nothing changed. Function, that changes value runs, but watch doesnt do anything.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels if I assign bool to the `shop` that is an object, it works:
`watch(bool, (newBool) => {
    console.log(newBool.isLoading)
  }, { deep: true })`

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new ref over a reactive data. It's like copying by value, the original reactive data and the new ref wrapped over it are not connected. So when `shop.isLoading` changes, your `bool` ref doesn't, they are two different variables now.

I guess you are using pinia for the store. If so, the `shop.isLoading` is already reactive, you don't have to wrap it into a `ref`.

```html
<Loading v-model="shop.isLoading" />
```

You can also use [`storeToRefs`](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/index.html#using-the-store) helper method from pinia to use destructuring over your store and get refs of your state:

```js
const { isLoading } = storeToRefs(shop)

console.log(isLoading.value)
```

Comment: I added additional code in the description so you'd understand what I want to do. It's conditional rendering. I know that I can use `shop.IsLoading` in `v-model` but logic of my app is a little bit different. And I really want to know how to detect changes in Vue the way I do it in React with useEffect.

Comment: You can use [`watchEffect`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watcheffect) which I guess is similar to react's `useEffect`. It will trigger for every reactive data change within its callback function.
Or `watch(bool)` (and not `watch(bool.value)` to react to your ref changes.

Answer (score 0):

So.
The problem was that I used `async` but I didn't use `await` inside the function and that's why condition worked the way it worked. Or didn't work as I expected.
Now I fixed it and I want to publicly admit that **I am a complete moron**.
Thank you for your attention.
P.S.
Still didn't figure out how to use `watch`. The only way is to watch the whole state object. `watch` doesn't react to only `state.bool` value change.

Answer (score 0):

To watch a variable with a primitive type you can do sth like below

```
let simpleBoolean = false;
watch(
    () => simpleBoolean,
    () => console.log('simple boolean changed!', simpleBoolean)
);
```